# I can't see istio's traffic in Envoy outbound port 15001 or Envoy inbound port 15006

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

After deploy the sample application,I want to see the life of a Packet in ISTIO According to [this article](https://dramasamy.medium.com/life-of-a-packet-in-istio-part-1-8221971d77de).

After I execute the below command, I get nothing.

```
tcpdump -i calib5d7dbd52bc port 15006 -A
```

The calib5d7dbd52bc is a veth pair of the pod productpage-v1

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on calib5d7dbd52bc, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
>
> 0 packets dropped by kernel
```